# How to fill vectors by reading a file?

Tags: c++, string, vector, ifstream

I am trying to read a file which contains the adjacency list as

1   37  79  164 15 
2   123 134 10  141 13

where first number in every line is vertex and following numbers are its adjacent vertices.

This is my code to read from the file . I have been able to put a line in a string but don't know how to proceed to populate the vector.

```
    ifstream ifs;
string line;
ifs.open("kargerMinCut.txt");
std::vector<vector <int> > CadjList(vertices);
while(getline(ifs,line)){
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Construct a `std::istrstream` from each line in the `while` loop and keep reading the numbers from it until there aren't any.

Comment: @RSahu Could u post some code please??

Comment: @RSahu: bad advice. `std::istrstream` operates on pointers and was already deprecated in C++98. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/istrstream

Comment: @ChristianHackl That was a typo. I meant to suggest `std::istringstream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stringstream` in the sstream header.

```
ifstream ifs;
string line;
ifs.open("kargerMinCut.txt");
std::vector<vector <int> > CadjList(vertices);
while(getline(ifs,line)){

    // transfer the line contents to line_stream.
    stringstream line_stream( line );

    // transfer line_stream to int variables.
    int tail_node;
    if ( line_stream >> tail_node ) // now do whatever you want with it.
    {
        int head_node;
        while ( line_stream >> head_node )
            CadjList[tail_node].push_back( head_node );
    }    
}
```

Comment: @Abhishek_Bansal Dude, I am getting segmentation fault(core dumped) error when executing above code. I even commented the line CadjList[tail_node].push_back( head_node ); and just printed tail_node , but still the same error.

Comment: If your vertex indices start from 1 and not 0, then you should modify the line to CadjList[tail_node-1].push_back( head_node ); or you should form a vector of (1+vertices) vectors instead of (vertices) vectors.

Comment: You should accustom yourself to using either `istringstream` or `ostringstream` depending on whether you need input or output, rather than the general `stringstream`.

Answer (score 6):

Use the power of STL! ;-)

- [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to create a stream from a string.
- [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to copy stuff from something to something else (yes, it can be that generic!).
- [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) to read and write to stream with an iterator interface, very useful in combination with `std::copy`.
- [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to use `push_back` with `std::copy`.
- [`std::vector`'s constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) can take iterators to initilize its content.
- [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) might be better than a `std::vector` if your vertex are not a continuous range starting from 0.

Which gives something like:

```
// vertex -> adjacent vertices
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> map;

std::string line;
while (std::getline(ifs, line))
{
    std::istringstream is(line);
    std::vector<int> ns;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(is), std::istream_iterator<int>(), 
              std::back_inserter(ns));

    assert(ns.size() > 1); // or throw something

    // The first is the vertex
    map[ns[0]] = std::vector<int>(ns.begin() + 1, ns.end());
}
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/CVz2J1)

Alternative implementation, assuming the file is not corrupt:

```
// vertex -> adjacent vertices
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> map;

std::string line;
while (std::getline(ifs, line))
{
    std::istringstream is(line);
    std::vector<int> ns;

    // assuming we know for sure the file is valid
    auto it = std::istream_iterator<int>(is);
    auto end = std::istream_iterator<int>();
    auto vertex = *(it++); // and not ++it !
    map[vertex] = std::vector<int>(it, end);
}
```

[**live example**](http://ideone.com/xiQnRM)

Generally speaking, [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) contains **many** nice functions.

Comment: The file format is specific where each line denotes an adjacency list. You cannot insert all elements one after the other.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal then you didn't understood my code: the `ns` is copied into the `map` with the first element as the key and the rest as the value.

Comment: Aah Ok, sorry I misunderstood.

Comment: I've added another impl that might be easier to read but less robust.

Answer (score 1):

Code in the while loop:

```
while(std::getline(ifs,line))
{
  std::vector<int> temp;
  std::istringstream str(line);
  int n;
  while ( str >> n )
  {
     temp.push_back(n);
  }

  CadjList.push_back(temp);
}
```