# C++ reading txt iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I need to deduce length of text file and save the numbers it contains (int) in a vector. I wrote' the code below:

```
    std::ifstream data(file_in);

    unsigned length=distance(std::istream_iterator<int>(data),std::istream_iterator<int>());

    copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(data),std::istream_iterator<int>(),vec.begin());
```

However, even if the length is correct, no number is saved into my vector, but if I remove the second line numbers are saved. I think it's a problem of iterator... but I don't know how to solve it, do I need to use the function advance?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please.

Comment: And that's what the "single pass" means in "single pass iterator"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've no idea how you use `length` in your code but here is a small piece of code that do what you need:

```
std::ifstream data(file_in);
std::vector<int> vec;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(data), std::istream_iterator<int>(), 
          std::back_inserter(vec));
```

All the magic is handled by [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter). There's no need to compute the length of the file.

You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24095209/520217) a similar problem.

Comment: Even better, initialize the vector using the iterators.

Comment: I need to calculate the length!

Comment: @chris: yes, unless `vec` is a member variable. Since the OP is using `copy` I used it too.

Comment: @user3758182: what's wrong with `vec.size()`?

Comment: @Hiura, If it's a member, initialize it with a constructor initializer list.

Comment: @chris and then you have to have `data` as a member too which might not make sense, or as a parameter but this might not be the OP's original design. Anyway, in the linked answer I show how to construct a vector from iterators.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point trying to count the number of integers that way. You can only do that by parsing the file, and if you've done that, why parse it again?

```
std::ifstream data(file_in);
std::vector<int> vec;
int i;
while (data >> i)
{
    vec.push_back(i);
}
```