# C++: Trying to read from a file line by line, saving into a vector and then printing the vector prints nothing

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream

I am trying to read from a file and insert the data into a vector. The file looks like:

```
16
0100
0111
0111
0001
0100
1011
1010
0010
0110
1001
1100
1001
1100
0101
0101
0001
```

I want my vector to look something like:

```
16 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1...
```

My code looks like this:

```
void readFile(string name){
    ifstream fin;
    vector<int> graphData;
    int y;
    fin.open(name);
    if (!fin.is_open()){
        cout << "Error: Could not open data.";

    }
    else{
        while(!fin.eof()){
            fin >> y;
            graphData.push_back(y);
        }

    }
    fin.close();
    for(int i = 0; i < graphData.size(); ++i){
        cout << graphData[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure the issue is with me defining y and then trying to push that in. But when I run the code nothing is outputted like the vector is empty.

Comment: Not related to the question: In such cases use try and catch, it'll always help

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094834/how-to-fill-vectors-by-reading-a-file?rq=1

Comment: I mean use getline

Comment: Also the output would be: "16 0100 0111 ..." not as you specified

Comment: Can I get it where the output would be 16 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1... I want each number to be in its own index

Comment: I think @Thomas Matthews already provided an answer for that, you can go ahead and mark that answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could - after skipping the line count - read in each individual character and compare it to `'0'` or `'1'`. See the following code:

```
int main() {

    vector<bool> bits;
    ifstream f(DATAFILE);
    if (f.is_open()) {
        int dummy;
        f >> dummy;
        char c;
        while (f >> c) {
            if (c == '1') {
                bits.push_back(true);
            }
            else if (c=='0') {
                bits.push_back(false);
            }
        }
        f.close();
        for(int i = 0; i < bits.size(); ++i){
            cout << bits[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this works great for me. I think I can go from here to continue on with what I am doing. Thank you for your help

Comment: You are welcome; please be so kind to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the numbers as character strings:

```
unsigned int quantity = 0;
fin >> quantity;
fin.ignore(100000, '\n');
std::string number_text;
vector<int> binary;
while (getline(fin, number_text))
{
  for (int i = 0; i < number_text.length())
  {
    int bit = number_text[i] - '0';
    binary.push_back(bit);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use getline function to get input line by line:
After `fin.open(name);`

do this:

```
getline(fin,line);
```

and then save the `line` to your y

Comment: Another example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line